# Is there a way to record the bluetooth data from others apps in android

Tags: java, bluetooth

Ok so I am trying to record the bluetooth data sent from another app and was wondering if that's possible. Operating system is androind, language is Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can enable "Bluetooth HCI snoop log" in developer settings. This generates a binary file you can explore for example with Wireshark.

More details on this process [here](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-capture-Bluetooth-traffic-from-and-to-an-Android-Device), but you might need to adopt it to your actual android version.